# Convert Bin Armstrong

Tags: python-3.x

Write another function called bin_armstrong() to find the binary string of all Armstrong numbers in a given range of numbers. The function also receices n1 and n2 as parameters as the previous question. Use a for loop.

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you share it even it's wrong ?

Comment: That looks like your homework, not ours.  You're the one that should be doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
def bin_armstrong(i, j):
    for a in range(i, j):
        a3 = sum(map(lambda x: int(x)**3, list(str(a))))
        if a == a3:
            print(str(bin(a)).split('b')[1])
```